# Weird databinding issues in wpf combobox

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox, mvvm-light

I am writing what is turning out to be a simple GUI in WPF.  At the moment I have a static list inside of a ComboBox, like this:

```
    <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="24,97,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="83"
        SelectedItem="{Binding fruit, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ComboBoxItem>apple</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>orange</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>grape</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>banana</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

I'm binding the SelectedItem to a singleton in my code that has already been initialized and used elsewhere.

I put a breakpoint on the `get` of `fruit` and it returns "grape", but the selected item is always blank.  I even added a button so that I could call RaisePropertyChanged manually, but the RaisePropertyChange call didn't do anything either.

Finally, MVVMLight gives blendability.  For no important reason I changed the binding in the combobox from `SelectedItem` to `Text`  As soon as I did that, my design time form filled in with the expected values, but, when the code is running, the box continues to sit at the empty state

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you have items of type `ComboBoxItem` in the `ComboBox` but the property you are trying to bind to is of type `string`.

You have three options:

1.Instead of adding `ComboBoxItem` items add `String` items:

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="24,97,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="83"
    SelectedItem="{Binding fruit, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <sys:String>apple</sys:String>
    <sys:String>orange</sys:String>
    <sys:String>grape</sys:String>
    <sys:String>banana</sys:String>
</ComboBox>
```

2.Instead of `SelectedItem` bind to `SelectedValue` and specify `SelectedValuePath` as `Content`:

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="24,97,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="83"
    SelectedValue="{Binding fruit, Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectedValuePath="Content">
    <ComboBoxItem>apple</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>orange</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>grape</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>banana</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

3.Do not specify items directly in XAML, but use `ItemsSource` property to bind to a collection of strings:

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="24,97,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="83"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Fruits}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding fruit, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks.  SelectedValuePath is exactly what I needed.  I didn't want to bind the ItemsSource because the list isn't going to change after release and I'm using some triggers based on certain selections.

Answer (score 1):

You should bind `ComboBox.ItemSource` to a list of strings (make the List of strings an `ObservableCollection<string>` in case you add items to this list) and then set the `fruit` variable to an instance in the List of strings.

I think you have your problem because your `fruit` variable references a different instance than you have in your list of `ComboBoxItems`. (even though the strings are the same)

Comment: then how do you explain that the problem goes away inside of blend?